# Can I use "more younger" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, comparatives

For example:

> Who looks *more younger* in this image, me or you?

Comment: Some times, *more* can be used with adjectives that normally have the *-er* suffix, for changing the emphasis/ subtle difference in sense. So, it would fine to say "Who looks **more young** in this image, me or you?" -- but not both * *more younger*.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: more younger equals to younger-er which is not correct. The same way Best-est or Better-er are not correct

Comment: Sorry, Kris, but I don't see any subtle difference using more young.  Younger means the same thing here, and is not awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 'younger' already has the meaning of 'more young'. The phrase 'more younger' would mean 'more more young'.

If there are two people in the photo you can say,

*Who looks younger, me or you?*

If there are more than two people, you say,

*Who looks youngest?*

Comment: There's a subtle difference between saying "younger" and "more young" though. See also my comment at OP.

Comment: Ahem.  *Who looks younger, you or I?*